# "No functions found" warning importing external dll file

Tags: c++, matlab, dll

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to work with some C++ dll files with Matlab, and I'm trying to implement a simple test case to understand the procedure.   The dll file I'm using is copied verbatim from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

I only implement up to step 5, since my hope is to call the dll file through Matlab.  After completing step 5, I copy MathLibrary.h and MathLibrary.dll to the directory I'm using for my Matlab code, and then run

```
[notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary('MathLibrary.dll','MathLibrary.h');
```

Upon running this I get the warning

```
>Warning: No functions found in library. 
>
>In C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\toolbox\matlab\general\loadlibrary.p>loadlibrary at 431
```

The cell array notfound is empty and warnings is an array with warnings = MathLibrary.h

If I try using one of the functions from the dll, I execute the following code:

```
calllib('MathLibrary','Add',5,3)
```

which throws the following error

```
>Error using calllib
>
>Method was not found.
```

I've tried Googling solutions to similar problems, but have not found solutions where I've looked (at least ones I've understood).  My C++ is weak, which may be hindering my understanding of the problem and solution.  I'm hoping to incorporate dll files from a much larger project soon, so understanding this would be a great help.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you compile it as specified in step 4? It looks like the functions are not exported correctly.

Comment: Does Matlab know how to deal with classes these days? I've only ever used it with a C wrapper.

Comment: Recommend finishing off the tutorial to ensure that you did generate the DLL correctly. Whether more recent matlab versions can interpret C++ classes or not, you can't expect much if the DLL is invalid or incomplete. Also recommend looking into matlab's mex files.

Comment: @Jørgen I didn't realize I had to compile that separately - I just compiled that file from the command line as the comment suggested and moved the resulting dll into the appropriate directory, but still get the same error from Matlab.

Comment: @user4581301 I'll finish the tutorial to be sure it worked, but Mex files aren't really an option.  There's hundreds of files in the project I'm hoping to interface Matlab with, and copy & pasting all of those files and re-building them in Matlab, and debugging them, would probably take weeks, if I was ever able to finish.

Comment: I hear you on that. You're doomed to a bit of tweaking though. Watch out for the differences in how matlab and C++ like their memory organized because you can suffer some serious performance hits and do your best to stick to primitive datatypes when moving data back and forth between them.

Comment: One last note and I'm not putting this up as an answer because I'm still on Matlab 2008 and a lot could have changed since then. There could be a solution. But I don't think you can do this. Consider: there is no `Add` function for `calllib` to find. There is only `MathLibrary::Functions::Add`. How you specify this to matlab, I have no idea, but `libfunctionsview` may be helpful. Fortunately `MathLibrary::Functions::Add` is static so you don't need to play at passing objects around, but there are still name mangling and calling conventions to be dealt with.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the note.  I think I need to learn more about C++ before I can decide what needs to be done.  I'm hoping I can figure something out because this is central to what I was hired to do. Oh boy!

Comment: Apparently I didn't read you question properly. I don't think you can access the DLL's C++ functions/classes directly from Matlab. As noted in this [answer from Matlab Central](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154975) you need to declare the DLL interface as `extern "C" {...}`. This is what we do when accessing C++ DLL's, a C interface, but C++ on the inside.

Comment: Found the relevant documentation. Short answer, you can't do it directly. Read [Limitations to Shared Library Support](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-shared-library-support.html), it specifically states to declare functions with `extern "C" {...}`

Comment: @Jørgen Thanks for the pointers (pun intended).  I'll have to see what I can do with our software tools, otherwise I may have to take a Mex file route.  Thanks again!